# Array list class method that removes an element and returns a new list

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

I need to write a method as part of the array list class that accepts an element as a parameter

The method removes all instances of that element and then returns a new list with only that element

```
public List<E> removeSubList(E element) {
    ArrayList<E> removedList = new ArrayList<E>();
    while(array_list.contains(element)) {
        removedList.add(array_list.remove(array_list.indexOf(element)));}
        return removedList;
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far... two things:

1. Would this work?

And 2. I keep getting cannot invoke (method) on array type Object[], which array_list is

Thanks!

Comment: You're saying array_list is an array of objects (Object[]) and not an ArrayList? Could you make it an ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

First, your `cannot invoke (method) on array type Object[]` error means that your `array_list` variable is actually an array of `Object`s, as Joni answered.

The following code is a static method that takes an extra parameter of an `ArrayList`. This corresponds to your `array_list` variable.

```
public static <E> List<E> removeSublist( E elt, ArrayList<E> aList) {
        // first, count the number of occurrences of the element
        int numOccurrences = Collections.frequency(aList, elt);

        // remove all occurrences of elt from your list
        aList.removeIf( currentElt -> currentElt.equals(elt));

        // return a list with numOccurrences duplicates of elt
        return Collections.nCopies(numOccurrences, elt);
    }
```

Your loop approach would work too but it's more efficient to remove all occurrences at once and then return a list with the corresponding number of duplicates of `elt`. If you're going to use the loop approach, you need to put the `return` statement *outside* the loop.

To make this method part of a custom subclass of `ArrayList`, simply change the signature back to what you had originally. But make sure `array_list` is actually of type `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that duplicates will only be good if `equals()` and `==` are the same for the `E` object.

Comment: i would highly recommend looking at this class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html